# unable to import VisualBertForClassification

Tags: huggingface-transformers

When i try to run below line

```
from transformers import VisualBertForClassification, AdamW
```

I am getting error

```
----------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-ba4f4adad339> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from transformers import VisualBertForClassification, AdamW
      2 
      3 # Define the model
      4 model = VisualBertForClassification.from_pretrained(
      5     "uclanlp/visualbert-nlvr2-coco-pre",

ImportError: cannot import name 'VisualBertForClassification' from 'transformers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/__init__.py)
```

I have already tried to run `!pip install transformers` and

```
!pip install --upgrade transformers
```

but still not able to import VisualBertForClassification

Comment: There is no transformer called "VisualBertForClassification" in the [list of supported transformers](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/index). Did you mean `from transformers import VisualBertModel`? ([this transformer](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/visual_bert))